How to Combine Fine-Tuned Pre-Trained Models on a Custom Dataset in PyTorch?
I have a custom image dataset with 41 classes, and I've fine-tuned this dataset on six pre-trained models:

ConvNeXt
DenseNet
EfficientNet
RegNet
ResNet
Swin Transformers

After fine-tuning, I saved each model as a .pth file.
Now, I want to load these .pth files and combine the models to classify images.
Since the architectures of the pre-trained models are different, I encountered an "unknown keys" error when I tried to load the models. So how do i achieve my goal of combined training?
